# What is the best database to track users relations?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, cassandra

I need to track users relations in a social app, something like this:

```
UserA follow UserC, UserD, and UserE
UserZ follow UserC, UserD, and UserE
UserC follow UserA, UserD, and UserE
```

And so on.

First, I need a partition tolerant database so MySQL and its brothers are out of the game.

I look at couchdb but it creates a revision for each change, so, if your doc is like:

```
{
  uuid: uuid
  name: name,
  lastName: lastName
  follows: [ uuid1, uuid2, uuid3 ]
}
```

you will have this other revisions in the data base

```
(rev 1)
{
  uuid: uuid
  name: name,
  lastName: lastName
  follows: [ uuid1, uuid2 ]
}
(rev 2)
{
  uuid: uuid
  name: name,
  lastName: lastName
  follows: [ uuid1 ]
}
```

That is a lot of space, I know you can free this by some manual action but the problem don't disappear.

I look at Cassandra, and so far it looks like a good solution, it allows insertions with no extra space issues like couchdb. I can create a key space, then a column and then an store relations, something like this:

```
keyspace:{
  column:{
    ...
    uuidT:{ uuidA: timestamp, uuidB: timestamp, uuidZ }
    uuidF:{ uuidA: timestamp, uuidB: timestamp, uuidZ }
    uuidH:{ uuidA: timestamp, uuidB: timestamp, uuidZ }
    ...
  }
}
```

But I'm wondering if a graphical database is best for this.

Edit:

After surf for a answer I found this page that helps to chose a DB. http://nosql.findthebest.com/

Comment: Y U TAG COUCHDB WEN U NO WANT COUCHDB?

Comment: Actually I love all the couchdb magic, if you now a way to implement this in couchdb tell me

Comment: There's no way around the need to compact your DB in Couch.  Where you see a manual action, I see a set-and-forget cron job.

Comment: you are right in this 'set-and-forget cron job'

Comment: database compacting can be done programtically

Comment: I just updated my answer, [you can limit the number of revisions CouchDB keeps](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Accessing_Database-specific_options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, in CouchDB I always use arrays of objects, rather than just arrays of IDs.  Eg.

```
{
  uuid: uuid
  name: name,
  lastName: lastName
  follows: [ { _id: uuid1 }, { _id: uuid2 }, { _id: uuid3 } ]
}
```

This is for two reasons:

1. It allows you, if you want, to easily add other join data to that object that you might want. Eg. `{ _id: uuid1, followed_on: "2011-10-22" }`
2. It fits in nicely with the `include_docs=true` options for grabbing the associated doc in your view queries.

#### Update

Hey, check it out, [you can limit the number of revisions kept in the DB](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Accessing_Database-specific_options)

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB is meant as an offline DB.

I would suggest looking into a graphDB, neo4j comes to mind. I was introduced to it via Mozilla labs in Toronto a few weeks ago, the people there told me it was the least painful graphDB to get up an running (you can apt-get/brew it). You can make arbitrary relationships in it, however it doesn't partition. If you want a DB that you can rely on and you want to do arbitrary relationships, maybe [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.com/titan/) is worth looking at.